# How could I manage processes in a python-bash environment?

Tags: python, bash, process

I have a linux server used for scientific calculations.
The server provides `bsub < [filename]` for submitting [filename] to queues, the calculation would return files like "A.chk" after 2 hours;
And also `bjobs` for checking status of all jobs, including jobID, run status(RUN, PEND, EXIT), etc.
Now I want to meet the following demand:

> 1. Submitting A.sh to the server;
> 2. Waitting for the calculation terminates, assume that it generates B.chk;
> 3. Do another calculation with B.chk and an existing script C.py
> 4. Do all these stuff automatically in one .py script.

I've managed to get the latest jobID and run status in a python script.
And I've tried the following solution:

```
import os
import time

os.system("bsub < %s" %(A.sh))
job_ID = get_jobID()
while(get_runstatus(jobID) != "RUN" and get_runstatus(jobID) != "PEND"):
    time.sleep(30)

if "B.chk" in os.listdir():
    os.system("python C.py")
```

But the while cycle in the server occupies too much public resources, so I'm not willing to do that. Then I searched for solutions like `process.join()` in **SubProcess**, but the job squence on the server cannot be treated as subprocess in python. So I'm here asking you for better solutions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this doesnt answer your question fully, there is a Python API for LSF on github

https://github.com/IBMSpectrumComputing/lsf-python-api